# Vuejs 2 display template twice IE and Safari laravel with blade

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I made an autocomplete component and it works well in Chrome, but not in IE and Safari.

It displays the template twice in IE and Safari. It works but it shows the template in addition to the rendered HTML. See the image.

What did I do wrong?

```
<div id="main">
    <autocomplete></autocomplete>
</div>

<template id="autocomplete">
    <div>
        <div class="col">
            <section class="box clr1">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Welk product zoekt U?" v-model="query" v-on:keyup="autoComplete" class="form-control">
                        <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item" v-for="result in results">
                                    <span style="text-decoration: underline;cursor:pointer" v-on:click="showDetail(result.id)">@{{ result.title }}</span>...

        <div class="col">
            <section class="box clr1">
                <div>
                    <div v-for="detail in resultdetail">
                        <h1>@{{ detail.title }}</h1>
                        <h2>@{{ detail.page_title }}</h2>
                        <p v-html="detail.description"></p>...


Vue.component('autocomplete', {
        template: '#autocomplete',
        data: function () {
            return {
                show: false,
                query: '',
                results: [],
                resultdetail: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            autoComplete: function () {
                this.results = [];
                if (this.query.length > 1) {
                    axios.get('/getproductjson/' + this.query + '/0')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            this.results = response.data
                        }.bind(this))...
            showDetail: function (productId) {
                if (productId > 0) {

                    this.show = true;
                    this.resultdetail = [];
                    axios.get('/getproductjson/loremipsumdipsum/'+productId)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            this.resultdetail = response.data
                        }.bind(this))...
        }
    });
    new Vue({
        el: '#main'
    });
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet explorer [does not support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template) the `template` tag.

What you're seeing in Internet Explorer is your instantiated Vue, and, since IE doesn't implement `template` it just shows your template on screen.

In IE if you want to store your template in the DOM you typically have to use the a script template.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="autocomplete">
    ...
</script>
```